# Capybara, Cucumber: page.find(<selector>).text returns only characters vwxyz

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, cucumber, capybara

I am having the weirdest issue with capybara/cucumber/selenium/rspec.

I haven't been able to match any selectors by text with capybara. One example would be:

```
page.should have_selector('h2', :text=>'Thank you')
```

the page is a flat html and the markup is:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Thank you</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

So I tried to output the text of that h2 tag, in the case I was doing something wrong.

```
puts "text: "+page.find('h2').text
```

To my surprise, this is what the terminal says:

```
output: text: y
```

I started playing with the text, then I changed the markup of the page to:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the terminal gives me:

```
puts "text: "+page.find('h2').text
output: text: vwxyz
```

It doesn't matter what text the h2 has, it only picks up on characters vwxyz, space and slash (/)! It completely ignore every other character, including capital letters VWXYZ. With that all my assertions are failing.

This is my gem version:

```
$ gem --version
1.8.25
```

And this is the gem list:

```
builder (3.1.4)
capybara (2.0.2)
childprocess (0.3.6)
commonwatir (4.0.0)
cucumber (1.2.1)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.0, 1.1.3)
ffi (1.3.1)
gherkin (2.11.5)
jammit (0.6.5)
json (1.7.6)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.5.0)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
open4 (1.3.0)
Platform (0.4.0)
POpen4 (0.1.4)
rack (1.5.0)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rspec (2.12.0)
rspec-core (2.12.2)
rspec-expectations (2.12.1)
rspec-mocks (2.12.2)
rubygems-update (1.8.25)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.29.0)
spreewald (0.3.10)
watir (4.0.2)
watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
websocket (1.0.6)
xpath (1.0.0)
yui-compressor (0.9.6)
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you using FirefoxDriver?

Comment: This is a very strange issue. I never had something like this

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using FirefoxDriver. I tried to switch to Chrome and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Same problem. Please let me know if you can find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head a lot, I realized my Ruby version was 1.8.7. It was a long shot, but I installed 1.9 and it now works. I have no idea if there is an incompatibility issue with Ruby 1.8.7 and the gem versions I was using, or if it was bad installation, but this worked.

My advice to everyone experiencing similar weirdness with cucumber/capybara is to make sure all gems and dependent software is up to date.